# How to resolve an issue with TypeError: unsupported format string passed to numpy.ndarray.__format__

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have the following code, but the output is giving me an error.

```
possible_rolls = arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
roll_result = np.random.choice(possible_rolls,1,replace=True)
modified_result = roll_result + 11
action_succeeded = modified_result > 15

print("On a modified roll of {:d}, Alice's action {}.".format(modified_result, "succeeded" if action_succeeded else "failed"))
```

> TypeError: unsupported format string passed to
>   numpy.ndarray.**format**

Comment: Please share the entire error message, as well as a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

you could just use an f-string and access the value of the 1x1 array:

```
print(f"On a modified roll of {modified_result.item()}, Alice's action {'succeeded' if action_succeeded else 'failed'}.")
```

sample output:

```
On a modified roll of 13, Alice's action failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `modified_result` is an array, not a number:

```py
possible_rolls = arr = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20])
roll_result = np.random.choice(possible_rolls,1,replace=True)
modified_result = roll_result + 11
action_succeeded = modified_result > 15

print(type(modified_result))
>>> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

This will solve the problem:

```py
print("On a modified roll of {:d}, Alice's action {}.".format(modified_result[0], "succeeded" if action_succeeded else "failed"))

>>> On a modified roll of 13, Alice's action failed.
```

Comment: `modified_result` does not seem to be an array. Do you mean it is an array of size 1?

Comment: @SathishSanjeevi it is a ndarray, check the documentation (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html)  or print it's type like I did.